# PhpUnit tests refreshing the initial database

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

i'm using Laravel 8 and creating some unit tests with PhpUnit.
I've created more than 200 unit tests and all was working fine.
Today when i ran the command `php artisan test` i noticed it's taking more than usual and i stopped the command mid way. After that my initial database data was deleted for no reason. Note that i was running my unit test on a sepereate database specificaly made for the unit tests. Now my unit tests are running on the initial database found in the .env file and i don't understand why.
Any solutions?
This is a small snippet of a basic unit test code i created maybe you guys can find a small mistake that i can't seem to find.

this is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Account;
use App\Services\AccountService;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AccountTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_accounts_retrieved_from_database()
    {
        Account::factory()->create();
        $accountService = app(AccountService::class);
        $accountService->getAll();
        $this->assertDatabaseCount('accounts', 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your MigrateFreshSeedOnce.php for something strange? Are you changing the database settings everytime so yes have you cleared the cache in between? There are too many variables to pin point this bug with this code I think. Also you have cancelled a command so what would happen if you would have run it all the way through?

Comment: @N.Hamelink, I tried running the command fully and when it's done i went back into my database and same thing happened all my data from the initial database were gone. Also i couldn't find the class MigrateFreshSeedOnce.php that you told me about. Finally i tried clearing cache and re run the tests and same thing happened.

Comment: What's the output of `composer --version` and `composer why cakephp/core`?

Answer (score 0):

hello i was having this problem i don't know what causing it but this commands fix it for me. hope it helps you too.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache --env=testing
```